# Passive with "get" negation

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to negate get-passive? i.e.

```
The servers don't get deployed
```

meaning

```
The servers aren't deployed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate it.

A common meaning of *to get X* means to transition something into state X.

So "The servers don't get deployed" is more equivalent to "Action is not taken to deploy the servers."

"The servers aren't deployed" is referring to the state of the servers at that moment.  It can imply we aren't doing anything with them in the immediate future, but *don't get X* makes that explicit.

Comment: cool, the sentence with `get` from your explanation is exactly what I wanted to say. I thought, passive with `to get` is used only in informal speech and passive with `to be` is for both - state and action (process).

Comment: @RomanT - This US English speaker would say that *get* with the passive is informal ("You might *get* eaten by a bear") and using *to be* is more formal ("You might *be* eaten by a bear").